# Angular unit testing directive that uses transclusion not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is seems like I am not able to trigger events within a unit test for a directive that uses transclude even though the directive works fine in an actual application.  For example, here is a simple directive and unit test that will alert text:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yPLVJp?p=preview (this will alert properly)

Now here is the same exact code except this directive has a template and uses transclude:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wAqY2h?p=preview (for whatever reason, this does not alert properly)

Is there any reason that the second one, the directive that uses transclude, does not properly trigger the alert in the unit test like the first one does?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the directive that uses transclude does not trigger the alert is because it has an isolated scope :

```
scope: {}
```

and you defined your callback in it :

```
post: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.func = function($event) {
    alert('the unit test should trigger this');
  }
}
```

Due the transclusion, the directive and the transclude do not share the same scope but inherit from the same parent (see the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directivedefinitionobject) even it is difficult to understand).
If you want that the transclude element access to an element that is added to the scope by the directive, the directive must not create a new scope and add this function in the parent scope :

```
scope: false,
...
post: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.func = function($event) {
    alert('the unit test should trigger this');
  }
}
```

Then directive and transclude element can share the same scope.

Comment: Well the directive I am working on needs an isolated scope (the directive is a lot more complex than the one used to show the issue) so there is no way to unit test scope functionality for an isolated scope directive that uses transclusion?

Comment: You can use a service to provide unit tested functions to the scope of your directive